# Populating Combobox in a Table Column

Tags: sapui5

I have tied an ODataModel with a table. In the table one of the columns is dropdown list. The list has some 3 values. It's slightly confusing for me but how to go with such scenario? Do I have to tie another model consisting of the values I want in the dropdown and then have it's property bound to the response coming from the ODataModel which is tied to the table?

Is the following thing correct? but it may not be good if I have more values to be there in the dropdown and morever.... how to proceed if I want to bind this "key" mentioned below with "Status" in the ODataModel? Here I have tied the "value" property of combobox to the "StatusText" coming from ODataModel.
But I want to tie the "key" property of ListItem with "Status" from ODataModel(which is tied with the table) response

```
    oTable.addColumn(
  new sap.ui.commons.ComboBox({
  items: [
                              new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "New",key:"1"}).bindProperty("text","StatusText").bindProperty("key","Status"),
                              new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "In Process",key:"2"}),
                              new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "Completed",key:"3"})
                              ]
                          }).bindProperty("value","StatusText")
);
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I hope I got your point, but I think the binding topic is not clear to me :-)

Answer (score 0):

This works in the table, but I think your Combobox still has some error with the bindings.

```
var oCombobox = new sap.ui.commons.ComboBox({
      items: [
              new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "New",key:"1"}).bindProperty("text","StatusText").bindProperty("key","Status"),
              new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "In Process",key:"2"}),
              new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text: "Completed",key:"3"})
              ]
          }).bindProperty("value","StatusText");

oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    template : oCombobox,
    visible : true,
}));
```

Lets say you have a oData field called {Firstname}, defined in your result type (table) e.g. for this table, then you bind it in the table as:

```
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
    template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
        text : "{Firstname}",
        textAlign : sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Center
    }),
    visible : true,
}));
```

As far as I understand, you want to get the possible values out of your oData Service, but I think this is not possible in case of an dropdown / combobox because you get a table from your backend, each line has a value in one field -> how would your bind 3 values in one single table field?

I realised dropdowns in an own service, calling the dropdown values from the backend separately:

```
getDropdown : function() {

// Create JSON data model
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.loadData("/sap/opu/odata/sap/YOUR_SERVICE/YourEntitySet");
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

// Create a DropdownBox
var oDropdown = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox("DropdownBox", {
                        text: "{Firstname}",
                    });

oDropdown.setModel(oModel);

var oItemTemplate1 = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
                        text : "{Firstname}",
                    });

oDropdown.bindItems("/d/results", oItemTemplate1); 
// "/d/results" may vary depending on your path

// return the box
return oDropdown;

},
```

you can use the returning result in your table.

e.g. in view:

```
var dropdown = oController.getDropdown();
dropdown.placeAt("content");
```